# What user data has been leaked from MtGox's database during June 2011 hack?

Tags: security, mtgox, hacking, database, user-data

What user data has been leaked from MtGox's database during the June 2011 hack? Is the database still available for download anywhere, [like it was almost a year ago](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=19576.0)?

Answer (score 3):

It was details of 61016 user accounts as a CSV file with fields UserID,Username,Email,Password.  The passwords are hashed, and most of them salted too, but some (the oldest) are simple md5 hashes.

I just tried searching google for it and was unsuccessful.

I have a copy, and could make it available for download but don't know if that would be legal.  I'm guessing not.